# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress could not load custom certificate from cert-manager

Tags: nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I am using `cert-manager` with this custom wildcard certificate

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-myapp-issuer
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: app@example.com # CHANGE-ME
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: wildcard-myapp-com
    solvers:
      # ACME DNS-01 provider configurations
      - dns01:
          cloudDNS:
            serviceAccountSecretRef:
              name: clouddns-service-account
              key: dns-service-account.json
            project: myapp
        selector:
          dnsNames:
            - '*.myapp.com'
            - myapp.com
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: myapp-com-tls
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretName: myapp-com-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-myapp-issuer
  commonName: '*.myapp.com'
  dnsNames:
    - '*.myapp.com'
    - myapp.com
```

I am deploying Nginx ingress with kustomize

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: controller
        args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
        - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
        - --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
        - --ingress-class=nginx
        - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
        - --validating-webhook=:8443
        - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
        - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
        - --default-ssl-certificate=default/myapp-com-tls # NOTE THIS LINE
```

When I open the logs of the ingress controller, I could see this error

> Error loading custom default certificate, falling back to generate ││ local SSL certificate default/myapp-com-tls was not found

What I can do to troubleshoot this?

**UPDATE**

If I run

`kubectl get secret myapp-com-tls --namespace default`

It returns nothing. However, if I run

`kubectl get secret myapp.com-tls-qpmpr --namespace default`

It returns

```
NAME                      TYPE     DATA   AGE
myapp.com-tls-qpmpr   Opaque   1      47m
```

**However**, if I change to this on YAML, I get the same error

```
--default-ssl-certificate=default/myapp.com-tls-qpmpr
```

```
$ kubectl describe certificates myapp-com-tls -n cert-manager
Error from server (NotFound): certificates.cert-manager.io "myapp-com-tls" not found
```

Comment: (a) did you actually look at `kubectl -n default get secret` to ensure it was there? (b) be aware that cert-manager takes non-zero time to resolve the LE request loop, so you could be facing a race condition

Comment: I updated my question. Could you please check again?

Comment: That Secret having only 1 datum smells suspicious, did you check to see what's in it? The TLS ones usually have a key and a cert

Comment: There only the `key` in the secret, the cert is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because the certificate was not ready yet